# Error adding 'Using <Class library>' to Web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Events happened:

I have Created a Web API project 'EmployeeService'.
Added a class library project to the solution 'EmployeeDataAccess'
Added an ADO.Net Entity Data Model named 'EmployeeDataModel.edmx'
Attached the data table from the data base
Built it.
Added 'EmployeeDataAccess' reference to the Web API project, EmployeeService
Added a new controller 'EmployeesController'

Now when i am trying to write 'Using EmployeeDataAccess', An error appears saying 'The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oEwn.png)

[image]

[image]

App.Config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EmployeeDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EmployeeDataModel.csdl|res://*/EmployeeDataModel.ssdl|res://*/EmployeeDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLExpress;initial catalog=EmployeeDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to check if namespace `EmployeeDataAccess` is there in the assembly you are referencing. Namespace and assembly need not to be the same.

Comment: I did, but there was no use..!!

Comment: You need to check the class "Employee" to see which namespace it belongs to. Also check the properties of "EmployeeDataAccess" project and see what is the assembly name and default namespace configured there.